# how to align one image button and one textview in leftside

Tags: android

I want to align one image button and one `TextView`  with linear layout right side  side one button like. But, I am try to align but not work and below `xml` layout code:I have tried the code given bellow.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ph_txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/phone_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"

            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/phoneicon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome_txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1.25"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/welcome_text"
            android:textColor="@color/welcome_txt_color"
             android:textSize="35sp"
             />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Relative layout -> padding:left

Answer (score 0):

Give orientation to linearlayout and keep it horizontal

Answer (score -1):

Try this way

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ph_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/phone_text"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ph_txt"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcome_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1.25"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/welcome_text"
            android:textColor="@color/welcome_txt_color"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="left|center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
             android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this its works fine :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center" >

         <ImageButton
             android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         android:gravity="center" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```